# Fireplace, identification and removal component

Tags: fireplace, removal

I am curious what the purpose is of the black metal covers above this fireplace. Looking up from below, outside of the window, they are closed. Is this purely decorative? Is there any way to remove them? I don't see any obvious bolts. Only decorative studs.

They are not physically attached to the actual fireplace, only the wall.

[image]

The stubs are not hiding bolts as for as I can see. On some sides there is a small gap and you can see there is nothing.

[image]

It's rock-solid though. My fear is that it's somehow cemented in. I might not be able to take it down without destroying some of the brickwork.

Comment: can you post a close up picture of the decorative stubs? Please verify that the top of the metal structure is closed and not a gap, can air flow through the top?

Comment: @Ack closed at the top as well. I added a picture of the studs.

Comment: The lowest flower looks like it's perfectly centered on the mortar- that's where a bolt head/screw/leaded/anchor securing point should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's 100% decorative. And that looks to be a new-ish insert (or recently repainted and rebricked).

You'll have to get into the fireplace and see with a scope or mirrors where they go, but I'm guessing it's just drilled into the facade brick and screwed in under those flower heads.

It does look pretty cool though. My wife would kill me however if I put it in.

Comment: I have added a picture of the flower heads. There's nothing behind them. But you are right, the wife wants to take it down :D

Comment: Interesting. If you take a shim / ruler and slide it up, I'm betting you'll hit one. In theory they should have drilled into the mortar, and not the bricks, so that's where I would expect to find any bolt heads. The other possibility is that it's only attached at the top on a pair of clips- so if you tried to 'lift up' from the bottom, it may shift upwards. IE it's hanging off of a couple of anchor bolts. And if it were, there is probably 1 bolt/screw that 'secures' the bottom to the wall so it doesn't move outwards (given the gap you show)

Answer (score 0):

If those "stubs" (did you mean "studs?) don't have any obvious way to tighten them, they may indeed be just decorative. If that's the case, I would have made the entire assembly hang from a hidden bracket at the top. So the bracket would be bolted into the brick and have a protruding lip, then a matching lip on the inside and at the top of the decorative element would allow the installer to hang it with the bracket not showing, kind of like a giant picture hanger. The sides however may be cemented to the brick to keep in in place, which would make it difficult to remove.

And I agree, that would be cool for a "bachelor pad", but my wife would ahve made me remove it immediately.

Comment: You might be right. I have added a picture of the stubs. The whole thing does not budge one millimeter so I assume it  might be cemented in place.